# Why am I only getting one solid bar when I plot my ggplot2 bar plot in my r Shiny app using uploaded data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am attempting to build my first Shiny app. I can upload a .csv file with a simple data set I created and display the table just fine in the first tab. I then try to use the same data to create a bar plot using ggplot2. Outside of Shiny, the bar plot generates perfectly. BUT inside the app it generates a plot with one bar and not bars representing the count of each "Pet" type, as it is supposed to, just a bar representing the count of all rows (30). I'm not sure why it won't count each type of "pet" in Shiny, please help?

I have tried using is.character and is.factor

The data column that the script uses is 30 rows of different types of pets (e.g. dog, cat, bird, lizard). The final plot should be a bar plot with a count of each type of these pets.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)
```

MY UI CODE:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

# App title ----
titlePanel("Magic Pets"),

# Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
sidebarLayout(

# Sidebar panel for inputs ----
sidebarPanel(

  # Input: Upload .csv 
  fileInput('file1', 'Choose .CSV File',
            accept=c('text/csv',
                     'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain',
                     '.csv')),


  selectInput("xcol", "Pets", "", selected = "")),


# Main panel for displaying outputs ----
mainPanel(

  # Output: Tabset for data table and plot
  tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
              tabPanel("Pet Data", DT::dataTableOutput('contents')),
              tabPanel("Lucky Pet Plot", plotOutput("MyPlot"))

      )
     )
    )
   )
```

MY SERVER CODE:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

output$MyPlot <- renderPlot({
z <- myData()[,input$xcol]

p <- ggplot(z, aes(x=input$xcol, fill = input$xcol)) + 
geom_bar(stat="count")
print(p)

})

myData <- reactive({
req(input$file1) # require that the input is available


df <- read_csv(input$file1$datapath) 


updateSelectInput(session,
                  inputId = "xcol", label = "Pets",
                  choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[sapply(df, 
is.character)])

return(df)
})


# Generate an HTML table view of the data ----

output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable({
DT::datatable(myData()) 
})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Consider `as.character` or `as.factor` instead of `is.character` and `is.factor`. They are different.

Comment: ah yes, i did try that. it did not help I'm afraid, but thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Magic Pets"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Upload .csv 
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose .CSV File',
                accept=c('text/csv',
                         'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain',
                         '.csv')),


      selectInput(inputId = "xcol", label = "Pets", choices = "", selected = "")

      ),


    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      # Output: Tabset for data table and plot
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Pet Data", DT::dataTableOutput('contents')),
                  tabPanel("Lucky Pet Plot", plotOutput("MyPlot"))

      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  myData <- reactive({
    req(input$file1) # require that the input is available

    df <- read_csv(input$file1$datapath) 

    return(df)

  })

  observe({ # observe is similar to recative expect that it doesn't yield results
    updateSelectInput(session,
                      inputId = "xcol", 
                      label = "Pets",
                      choices = names(myData()),
                      selected = names(myData())[1] # select 1st column name
    )

  })

  output$MyPlot <- renderPlot({
    #z <- myData()[,input$xcol] #not needed

    p <- ggplot(myData(), aes_string(x=input$xcol, fill=input$xcol)) + 
      # aes_string allows you to use strings or quoted names/calls to define the aesthetic mappings
                  geom_bar(stat="count")

    print(p)

  })

  # Generate an HTML table view of the data ----

  output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(myData()) 
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Two things to note:

1. use `observe` (which is similar to `reactive` but without yielding results) to update the input
2. use `aes_string` instead of `aes` to allow using stings or quoted names to define the aesthetic mappings. Note that `input$xcol` returns `"pet"` not `pet`.

Comment: It works beautifully now, thank you so much :)  I still have much to learn about shiny!